# Solution to iPad's image loading restriction

Tags: javascript, ipad, mobile-safari

Seems like iPad stops loading Images in a HTML / JavaScript application after a certain point (around 6MB) after which all images in the application are shown as blank or '?'.

If using `<img>` tags is a problem, then is there a solution or alternative to this in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

It appears you can use a canvas tag. From [this source](http://roblaplaca.com/blog/2010/05/05/ipad-safari-image-limit-workaround/):

> I found the easiest way to patch my
>   code was to load the image into a
>   canvas tag using drawImage(). The
>   canvas tag appears to be immune to the
>   limitation.

Another solution is to simply cut the content in several pages, each one with less than 6MB in images. That way when you reload the browser resets the limit.